# How would I write contents from inherited list to a text file?

Tags: c#

I'm probably going about this the completely wrong way, but I'm trying to write the contents from an inherited list into a text file using a method, called Load.

```
public class Appointments : List<Appointment>
```

There are no problems here, however when I try to write each item from the list into a text file with the code:

```
public bool Load(string fileName) 
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Appointment.txtr");
    foreach (string s in List<Appointment>)
    {
        tw.WriteLine(s + "\n");
    }
}
```

I get the error `"List<Appointment>" is a type which is not valid in the given context.`

Any ideas how I can fix this? Or has anyone got another way of doing what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Load() method is declared in Appointments class?

Comment: You're not inheriting from `string` as far as I can see...

Comment: foreach (string s in List<Appointment>) - not sure what language you talk, but that is not valid C#.

Comment: Leaving your actual question aside for the moment: it is a bad programming practice to inherit from List unless you are making a new list abstraction.  A type representing appointments should **contain** a list of appointments, not **be** a list of appointments.

Comment: @DanielA.White: How would that work? An appointment is an Appointment, not a string.

Comment: Take a step back.  Suppose you have a *single* appointment. Not a list, just an Appointment.  How do you turn that thing into a string?  Is there a ToString method? If not, you need to write one. Start by writing a program that does that.

Comment: Also, why are you calling writeline and then writing a newline?  Writeline already writes a newline.

Answer (score 3):

`List<Appointments>` is a type...In foreach loop,you have to use instance of class which is of type IEnumerable..In your case, Appointments which inherits `List<Appointments>` which in turn is of type IEnumerable. So instance of Appointments is what you should use in foreach loop. As the load method in that class itself..you can do something like this

```
public bool Load(string fileName) 
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Appointment.txtr");
    foreach (Appointment a in this)
    {
       var s = a.ToString(); // code which converts appointment to string
        tw.WriteLine(s + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you give cannot be right; you're casting an Appointment to string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Load` is a member of `Appointments` you can do this:

```
public bool Load(string fileName) 
{
    using(TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Appointment.txtr"))
    {
        foreach (Appointment a in this)
        {
            tw.WriteLine(a.ToString() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

By doing the `foreach` over `this` you'll access the items in the base `List` class.

NOTE: You forgot to close the writer, so I've added a `using` block to take care of this.

On another note, calling the method `Load` is a bit misleading as you're actually saving the data to a file, rather than loading it. I suspect a better name would be `Save`.